# FileOutputStream Reflection

Tags: java

I was just wondering if there was some way I could actually rename the method of the FileOutputStream using reflection in Java. I'm in a Java programming class in college, we just went over how reflection works. Our assignment was to make an example and I choose to do use it with the FileOutputStream. I have this code so far:

```
import java.io.*;

FileOutputStream One;

try {
  One = new FileOutputStream("Example.txt");
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println("Error! - " + e);
}
```

So what would I do is rename FileOutputStream to maybe like TickTok, but it would do the same function. However, what I'm really stuck on is how I would go about doing this. Does anyone know how I would do this?

Edit: What I mean is like

```
One = new FileOutputStream("Example.txt");
```

to:

```
One = new TickTok("Example.txt");
```

Comment: You haven't actually *used* any methods of FileOutputStream in your code, so I'm not sure what it's meant to be demonstrating. But reflection can't rename methods, no.

Comment: Rename *what* method? And for gosh sakes *why*?

Comment: What I mean is like One = new FileOutputStream("Example.txt"); to One = new TickTok("Example.txt");

Comment: @Hovercraft "I'm in a Java programming class in collage, we just went over how reflection works."

Comment: I doubt that's a valid Reflection use case. You could achieve this by other means such as wrapping its APIs within your custom TickTok class or extending the FOS class to your own TickTock class.

Comment: @moomonkey: that doesn't answer why you'd want to rename a class. (Or how you thing that should be possible with reflection. Think about it: reflection is a runtime thing. You're trying to change stuff at/before compile time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rename a method using reflection.  If you are interested in accessing a `Method` object that represents a method of the `FileOutputStream` class, it would be easiest to access using the `FileOutputStream`'s class member.  You can access this object in this way:

```
Class<FileOutputStream> fosClass = One.class; //using the reference to 'One' in your provided code.
```

From here, you can get one of its method's using [`getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29).

For example, to get the `write(byte[])` method of `FileOutputStream`, you could then call this:

```
Method writeMethod = fosClass.getMethod(byte[].class);
```

This method can then be invoked (using the [invoke](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method) on ***any*** instance of `FileOutputStream` like this:

```
writeMethod.invoke(One, new byte[]{100,101,102});
```

Answer (score 2):

`FileOutputStream` is a *class*, not a method. Regardless, reflection can't be used for any such thing.

From [Jakob Jenkov's reflection tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html):

> Java's Reflection API's makes it possible to inspect classes, interfaces, fields and methods at runtime, without knowing the names of the classes, methods etc. at compile time. It is also possible to instantiate new objects, invoke methods and get/set field values using reflection.

If you wanted the effect of referring to `FileOutputStream` as a different name, you could simply extend that class and match each of its constructors to with a call to `super` - however this would be pointless.

It sounds like you've been asked to demonstrate a use case of reflection, so my recommendation is to do more research on it to understand its uses and capabilities (by research I mean reading, not StackOverflow questions).

Answer (score 0):

You can use another name for the constructor by sub classing it.  However I you should only do this if you have a good reason to do so.  I this case I would document why you are doing it.

```
class TickTok extends FileInputStream {
   public TickTok(String filename) {
       super(filename);
   }
}
```

It worth remembering that reflection allows you to examine and use API programmatically, but to add or change it.

To do this you need to generate byte code using a library like ASM or the Compiler API.